# jQuery — Using .delay() to postpone a .load()?

Tags: jquery, load, delay

I've just run into an issue with using jQuery's .delay() method (v 1.4.2) to try to delay a following .load() method.

Like so:

```
$('myElement').delay(500).load('myPage.php');
```

It seems to just ignore the .delay().

I've evenutally figured out a work-around like so:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('myElement').load('myPage.php');
}, 500);
```

But, that's not as elegant. Anyone else run into this and found a better solution?

Thanks.

Comment: `.delay()` only delays functions that follow it in the effects queue

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, the the [`delay()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) method will be ignored, because the [`load()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method  is not automatically queued.

The `setTimeout` is probably your best option, though you could technically accomplish it with `.delay()` if you add the `load()` call to the queue using the [`queue()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) method.

```
$('myElement').delay(500).queue(function( nxt ) {
    $(this).load('myPage.php');
    nxt();
});
```

The function is added to the queue. You need to then call the parameter of the function to free up the queue. There's a method called the [`dequeue()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/dequeue/) method that can accomplish this as well.

Comment: +1 Interesting alternative to `setTimeout()`, providing animation on the given element is not being done.

Comment: @Orbling: Yes, good point. It is possible to create a separate queue so that anything in the default queue isn't affected. This method requires more overhead than a simple `setTimeout()`, and doesn't provide any real benefit that I can see, so I'd use the `setTimeout` instead.

Comment: Thanks for that excellent explaination Patrick, I understand this much better now.

Comment: @patrick dw: Aye, I always use `setTimeout()` - though I tend to feel a certain *non-jQuery-ness* about it, which tends to be an annoyance.  Not for performance reasons, it's even very functional in nature, just not quite the same.

Comment: I agree Orbling. Whenever I have to default outside of jQuery to do something I always "feel kinda weird" about it.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my solution to fading out a div, then loading new content into it, and then fading it back in. This is really usefull for AJAX calls to load search results for example.

```
$('.search').keyup(function(){
    var query= $(this).val();
    $('.results').fadeOut('300');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.results').load('search.php?search=' + query, function() {
            $('.results').fadeIn('300'); 
        })
    }, 300);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: You're welcome! Glad you got it working! Timing is always an issue with jQuery and the setTimeout never really did it for me (especially when you use multiple of them at the same time, something with the queue and what not). I feel that by using the animation duration as a delay, you have full control and multiple things can be "waiting" at the same time (or at different times!)

Answer (score 2):

If you use the jQuery timers plugin you can do

```
$('myElement').oneTime(500, function() { 
    $(this).load('myPage.php');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip Petah, I didn't know about the Timers plugin. I'm going to grab it and play around a bit now.

Comment: Voted down the answer as no link is provided to the particular 'timers' plugin referenced, as such, there is very little chance of being able to implement this answer and its usefulness is diminished.